# Given a directed graph, orient each edge in such way that there exists a way which goes over all edges exactly once

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures, graph, graph-algorithm

I was trying to solve the following question:[TOURISTS](https://www.codechef.com/problems/TOURISTS)

This is the editorial link of the problem:[editorial](https://discuss.codechef.com/questions/90320/tourists-editorial)

My solution:[solution](https://www.codechef.com/viewsolution/12678924)

Basically,we need to check whether the given graph exists Euler Circuit and if it's connected,if both the conditions are satisfied,then, such tour as in the statement exists.

In the solution,I have checked both the conditions which are required for an undirected graph to consist an **euler circuit** and used the **hierholzers-algorithm** to print the circuit as described in the problem statement,but for some reasons my code is not able to clear some of the test cases.

Can anyone please point out what condition am I missing in the code?

Comment: Why don't you add b as a neighbour of a in adj1?

Comment: because that is for checking if the given graph is connected or not,for that I am passing the given directed edge.

Comment: You want to find connectedness of the undirected graph, so you need both copies of the edge or it will be wrong.

Comment: I first did it using the undirected one,but with the directed edge,it helped to clear one of the test cases which was failing before.